# gnuplot pdfcairo unnamed Type 3 font in output on macos

Tags: macos, fonts, gnuplot

Gnuplot with the pdfcairo terminal seems to give strange behavior in terms of fonts, where the generated pdf has unnamed, Type 3 fonts. Here's output from pdffonts on the output pdf file:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  yes      5  0
HTVMTJ+Helvetica                     CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      6  0
ITRAZO+Helvetica                     CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      7  0
```

This is a problem because the publisher refuses to accept Type 3 fonts in documents. How do I get around this? Below is a small gnuplot file that reproduces the problem on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3, gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 5:

```
set terminal pdfcairo font "Helvetica, 16"
set output "../plots/test.pdf"
set xlabel "x-axis"
set ylabel "y-axis"
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]
plot 0.5 title "y=0.5"  w l lw 3
```

For now, my workaround is to use the postscript terminal and then epstopdf, but this requires a lot of rework on many many scripts. Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: I've zero-ed in on the "xtics" and ""ytics" as being the culprits for the Type 3 fonts. (If you add "set noxtics" and "set noytics" to the above script, the error goes away. But still, no luck resolving this.

Comment: It's been two years to this post now, but the issue still remains. Oddly this happens on MAC and not Linux. Has anyone been able to solve this? The bug report also doesn't help much: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1868/

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this issue too and narrowed it down to being *spaces*. Any time you add whitespace to an axis label or set the tic format to include space, you get an unnamed Type 3 font added. I can't even begin to understand why.

Comment: For my minimal example, this is not the case -- the axis labels don't have any white spaces, and there's no such formatting for the tics either. I'm not sure what's causing this. I filed a bug at Sourceforge, but the developer thinks the problem lies elsewhere (which I'm disinclined to believe): https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1868/?limit=25

Comment: I faced the same issue, without using spaces at all. The same plot scripts on Ubuntu do NOT produce the issue; on Mac they do!

Comment: I have this same issue using pdfcairo for Graphiz (dot) to PDF output. This answer seems correct in my case. If I remove all of the spaces from my node labels, then I just have one TrueType font in the output, but if I add even a single space to any node label then I get the `[none]  Type 3` font embedded in my output PDF. Also, I can confirm that the Type 3 font isn't added to the PDF if I run the same script on Ubuntu rather than my Macbook.